# No response from Cassandra database using SOLR

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, solrj

I have created a DataImportHandler in Apache SOLR to retrieve data from Cassandra database. 
My configuration as follows

solrconfig.xml:

```xml
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"     class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">dataconfig.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

dataconfig.xml:

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"     driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"
    url="jdbc:cassandra://192.92.12.2:9160/test"
    user="user1"
    password="passpass"
    autoCommit="true"/>
  <document name="content">
    <entity name="test" query="SELECT id from test.contacts" autoCommit="true">
      <field column="id" name="id" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml:

```xml
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

When I execute using solr admin getting the below response

> ```
> {
>   "responseHeader": {
>     "status": 0,
>     "QTime": 0
>   },
>   "initArgs": [
>     "defaults",
>     [
>       "config",
>       "dataconfig.xml"
>     ]
>   ],
>   "command": "status",
>   "status": "idle",
>   "importResponse": "",
>   "statusMessages": {
>     "Time Elapsed": "0:12:6.182",
>     "Total Requests made to DataSource": "0",
>     "Total Rows Fetched": "0",
>     "Total Documents Processed": "0",
>     "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
>     "Full Dump Started": "2016-09-05 10:52:52",
>     "Full Import failed": "2016-09-05 10:52:52"
>   }
> }
> ```

I can't identify what is the issue in this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Removed schema.xml and included the content in  **managed-schema** in /conf directory.

2) Added below dependency libraries.

[image: Dependency library]

And finally got output.

Comment: which conf directory? All I see is the example folder that contains example-DIH/solr/db/conf

Do you mind to share step by step how you exactly managed to integrate Cassandra to Solr?
Thanks

Comment: What cassandra version are you using? I use 3.4 and the cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar is not working properly?

Comment: @Sharavanakumaar Murugesan Can you give a little more insight? Why do you need mysql-connector-java?

Comment: @KaMok My application connects with mysql db also